# Загружается только часть файла PHP

Tags: php

Много лет работал парсер и вдруг сегодня ночью стал выдавать ошибку.
Я обращаюсь к XML файлу по ссылке при помощи функции simplexml_load_file, читаю его и вытаскиваю из него актуальное наличие.
После долгих мучений, выяснилось, что закачивается не полный файл, а только его маленькая часть. Пробовал функцией copy, cUrl-ом, file_get_contents. Ничего не помогает. Копируется маленький кусочек, 72 килобайта из 12 мегабайт, а остальное тело куда то пропадает. При этом в текстовом редакторе и браузере файл по ссылке открывается полностью.
Разговор с администратором сайта не помог. Админ утверждает, что кроме меня ни у кого не возникло сложностей.
В какую сторону смотреть? Что еще можно попробовать для загрузки.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Покажите проблемный код хотя бы?

Comment: Не скачивается полностью файл, а скачивается маленький кусочек. Только что попробовал на python, при помощи функции urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, 'kms2s.xml'), получил ошибку: http.client.IncompleteRead: IncompleteRead(0 bytes read)

Comment: Звучит как новые "чудо-настройки" фаервола на предприятии